# I have a D7000 Nikon camera that is continuously focusing and also showing a level indicator: how do I change this?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings

My camera is currently set to a weird setting, it shows lines on the screen that turn red yellow or green depending on the angle that I am holding the camera and is constantly adjusting focus depending on how I move the camera. How can I fix the source of this issue?

Comment: These are really two very separate things — they'd be better as two separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

These settings don't seem "weird".

It sounds like you have enabled "AF-F" mode — that's "full-time servo", where the camera tracks focus until you freeze it by pressing the shutter. You can disable that by changing to `AF-S` mode — autofocus-single.

Nikon calls the level-indicator "virtual horizon". Turn that off in the setup menu if you don't want it.

All of this is covered by [your camera's manual](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D7000_ENnoprint.pdf). It's probably going to be helpful to have a quick browse through. Or, at least, search for related terms like "focus" or "level" when you have a problem.